# Display selected text value of dropdown to button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the selected text value of my dropdown to my button.
I tried clicking on a text value of my dropdown but my button isn't displaying the selected text value of my dropdown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dropDownUl li")
  on('click', function() {
   $('#dropDownBtn').val($(this).text());
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="dropdown" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <button id="dropDownBtn" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle "
   type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
   Choose A Date <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul id="dropDownUl" class="dropdown-menu">
   <li class="text-center">16-12-2016</li>
   <li class="text-center">27-12-2016</li>
   <li class="text-center">01-02-2017</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As an aside, why are you using non-anchor elements as clickable elements? How would a keyboard-only user use your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `.text` property of `button` not `val`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#dropDownUl li").on('click', function () {
     $('#dropDownBtn').text($(this).text());
   });
});
```